# Get list of teams meeting participants via the graph api on behalf of another user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to call the graph api using c# and a app registration to get the list of team meeting participants for another user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

GET /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}

I can create an online meeting using my app registration but I cannot retrieve the meeting participants.  I keep getting a 403 error.  I have granted my app registration OnlineMeetings.Read.All and OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All.  What other permissions are needed to get the meeting participants on behalf of another user?

Comment: Create Online meeting don't have Application level support for Graph API., To get the meeting participants You need to go with custom specified external ID for users to get the participants. Please check this [CreateOrGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) documentation

Comment: I tried adding externalId but it returns null?  Is the externalid only supported via https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/ vs https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/onlineMeetings/

Comment: I see this note.  Not sure how to add that policy though? * Administrators must create an application access policy and grant it to a user, authorizing the app configured in the policy to create or get an online meeting with external ID on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the request path).

Comment: External ID can only be set with [CreateOrGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) API